# Using the default_url_options and path_params option within an ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you get an IntegrationTest to use the `default_url_options` method? I would like to take advantage of the [`path_params` option for `url_for`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43770).

Here is a simple example:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope ":blog_id" do
    resources :posts
  end
end

class BlogControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @blog = blogs(:with_posts).first
    @post = @blog.posts.first
  end

  # This test will raise `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches`
  test "accessing a post with default_url_options" do
    get post_url(@post)
    assert_response :success
  end

  # This test will pass
  test "accessing a post" do
    get post_url(post, blog_id: @blog.id)
    assert_response :success
  end

  private

    def default_url_options(options = {})
      { path_params: { blog_id: @blog.id } }
    end    
end
```

Comment: I would declare the route as `resources :blogs, path: nil, only: [] do; resources :posts; end` as that will let you treat it like any other nested resource instead of having to explicitly pass the `blog_id` key.

Comment: @max you would still have to pass the parent. This is just an example of where you want to have default path_params.